# Revert to restore point before `btrfs check --repair`

Tags: linux, btrfs

How do I make the operation of `btrfs check --repair` reversible without a full `dd` backup?

Is it sufficient to use:

```
btrfs-image -w <device> <image-file>
```

possibly using `-t <#-threads>` and `-c9` (highest compression) as well?

Will a restore of this image reverse the effect of all `check --repair` operations, including

- `--init-csum-tree`
- `--init-extent-tree`?

What is the use of the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with the details of btrfs but I see the risk that the metadata dump of a damaged filesystem might be incomplete.

I suggest that you use `dmsetup` to set up a snapshot device and run `btrfs check --repair` on the snapshot which you can just throw away so that you get the original state.

This snapshot will consume only little space after the repair run.

Answer (score 1):

`dmsetup` snapshots ([official documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/device-mapper/snapshot.txt)) can be used to store changes, and if they are acceptable, they can be merged into the original device.

- [Create a snapshot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67678/gnu-linux-overlay-block-device-stackable-block-device/67681#67681)
- [Merge a snapshot](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Device-mapper#Merging_snapshots)

[This reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/4npllq/anyone_using_device_mapper_snapshots/d4fhn84/) has detailed examples.

Note all [dmsetup(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/dmsetup.8.html) table sectors are 512 bytes:

> Devices are created by loading a table that specifies a target for        each sector (512 bytes) in the logical device.

Credit to [Hauke Laging's suggestion to use dmsetup](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/392696/143394).