# Can't create persistent snapshot device with `dmsetup`

Tags: block-device, snapshot, device-mapper

I am trying to create a `dmsetup` snapshot device be able to [rollback changes made by fsck](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/392624/143394).

I think I'm calling `dmsetup` incorrectly. Here's an example:

```
$ truncate -s 4096 real snapshot               
$ losetup --show -f real                       
/dev/loop0                                     
$ losetup --show -f snapshot                   
/dev/loop1                                     
$ sudo dmsetup -v create snapdev --table '0 8 snapshot /dev/loop0 /dev/loop1 P 1'
device-mapper: reload ioctl on snapdev  failed: Input/output error
Command failed
```

The two spaces after `snapdev` in the error message are slightly weird.

However, if I change the `P` for persistent to `N` for non-persistent, everything is ok:

```
$ sudo dmsetup -v create snapdev --table '0 8 snapshot /dev/loop0 /dev/loop1 N 1'
Name:              snapdev
State:             ACTIVE
Read Ahead:        256
Tables present:    LIVE
Open count:        0
Event number:      0
Major, minor:      254, 4
Number of targets: 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It may have something to do with the fact that you will lose the loopback device on reboot.

Comment: @RamanSailopal [These scripts](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/4npllq/anyone_using_device_mapper_snapshots/d4fhn84/) use a loop device, so I don't believe it's that.

Answer (score 1):

To be used for a persistent snapshot, the first few blocks of the device need to be `\0`. [This example](https://user.xmission.com/~ddmayne/slackware/snapshot_origin.html)
   zeros out the first 32 blocks.

[The bytes `SnAp\001` are written to the beginning of a persistent snap device](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/396979/143394).

The first block of the underlying device maps to block 16 of a persistent snapshot device. (Data starts at byte offset 8192 or 0x2000).

A snapshot device [needs to be an (unspecified) minimum size](https://serverfault.com/a/505664/322507). 4MB is sufficient.

Resources:

- [Details of one persons explorations and findings](https://user.xmission.com/~ddmayne/slackware/snapshot_origin.html)
- [Scripts for creating, deleting and merging snapshots](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/4npllq/anyone_using_device_mapper_snapshots/d4fhn84/)
- [How to create snapshots on a live device](https://www.redhat.com/archives/dm-devel/2004-July/msg00071.html)
- [Redhat's device mapper appendix](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/logical_volume_manager_administration/device_mapper)
- [Kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/device-mapper/snapshot.txt)
- [Gentoo wiki](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Device-mapper)