# What size blocks does `truncate --io-blocks` use?

Tags: files, block-device, coreutils, truncate

What size blocks does GNU [`truncate --io-blocks`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/truncate.1.html) use?

> ```
>       -o, --io-blocks
>              treat SIZE as number of IO blocks instead of bytes
> ```

- 512 bytes
- `blockdev --getbsz`
- `blockdev --getpbsz`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the above.

The blocksize is related to the filesystem parameters chosen at mkfs time, and can be found by running `stat()` against the file. It has no relation to the underlying block device the file system is stored on (if any).

For example, with GNU `stat`:

```
$ /usr/bin/stat . | grep IO.Block       
  Size: 71680           Blocks: 144        IO Block: 2048   directory
```

If you prefer a more programmatic view, the `stat()` system call can be made in `perl` with:

```
$ perl -e '@x=stat("."); print $x[11]'
2048
```

In both cases we get "2048" as the answer for this filesystem.

We can verify this:

```
$ truncate -o -s 1 foo      
$ ls -l foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 sweh sweh 2048 Sep 17 10:28 foo
```

Different filesystems can have different block sizes.  eg on my machine I made the `/news` disk use smaller block sizes because it stores mostly smaller files

```
$ perl -e '@x=stat("/"); print $x[11]'
4096

$ perl -e '@x=stat("/news"); print $x[11]'
2048
```

For Linux `extx` file systems, this is done with `mke2fs` with the `-b` flag:

```
   -b block-size
          Specify  the  size  of blocks in bytes.  Valid block-size values
          are 1024, 2048 and 4096 bytes per block.  If omitted, block-size
          is  heuristically  determined  by  the  filesystem  size and the
          expected usage of the filesystem (see the -T option).  If block-
          size  is preceded by a negative sign ('-'), then mke2fs will use
          heuristics to determine the appropriate  block  size,  with  the
          constraint  that  the  block  size  will  be at least block-size
          bytes.  This  is  useful  for  certain  hardware  devices  which
          require that the blocksize be a multiple of 2k.
```

Comment: Also keep in mind that the block size of a NFS mounted share here relates to the `rsize` mount option, nevertheless the block size of the underlaying filesystem.

Comment: @Thomas yes, there are many ways the blocksize can change, which is why running `stat()` against the file (which is what the code does) is required to get the right answer.  And it should, really, be against the _file_ and not the directory, because you can get different results there, as well.

Comment: It's unclear why `truncate` has that `--io-block` in the first place though (FreeBSD where that utility first came from in 2000) doesn't have it, nor why it's not implemented as a suffix for the size (like `truncate -s1B`). It's been there from the start apparently. I can't imagine it being a common use case.